# Read and show header and Image from DICOM file in C#

Tags: c#, dicom

How to show Image and header in Frame of windows form from a DICOM file in C# using GDCM Library?can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this example:

http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/HelloVTKWorld_8cs-example.html

It uses GDCM & VTK.